# How to make while loop work properly to correct given 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, debugging

I'm trying to write a method that will take a two-dimensional array as an input, and return a new 2D array in which all the zeroes are removed from the array.

Also, if there is an element in the first array that has a value equal to the length of the second array, then it should be removed and all elements in the second array will be subtracted by 1.

The above process should be repeated for the second array also.

This is what I've written for the code implementation so far, but the code gets stuck in a loop and I don't think it's doing what it's supposed to do.

Note: When ArrayUtils is called, the Apache Lang library is being used, and this is the 2D array I inputted:

```
[[0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 4], [0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Code:

```
public static int[][] removeTrivialCases(int[][] startingSums) {
    int[][] correctedSums = startingSums;

    int counter = 0;

    int numRows = correctedSums[0].length;
    int numCols = correctedSums[1].length;

    boolean zeroesExist = true;
    boolean valueEqualsDimension = true;

    boolean trivialCasesRemain = true;

    while(trivialCasesRemain) {
        for (int i = 0; i < correctedSums.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < correctedSums[i].length; j++) {
                if (correctedSums[i][j] == 0) {
                    trivialCasesRemain = true;
                    correctedSums[i] = ArrayUtils.removeElement(correctedSums[i], j);
                }

                for (int h = 0; h < correctedSums[i].length; h++) {
                    if (correctedSums[i][h] == 0) {
                        zeroesExist = true;
                    }
                }

            }
        } 

        for (int i = 0; i < correctedSums[0].length; i++) {
            if (correctedSums[0][i] == numCols) {
                trivialCasesRemain = true;
                correctedSums[0] = ArrayUtils.removeElement(correctedSums[0], i);
                for (int j = 0; j < correctedSums[0].length; j++) {
                    correctedSums[0][j]--;
                }

                valueEqualsDimension = false;

                for (int h = 0; h < correctedSums[0].length; h++) {
                    if (correctedSums[0][h] == numCols) {
                        valueEqualsDimension = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }   

        for (int i = 0; i < correctedSums[1].length; i++) {
            if (correctedSums[1][i] == numRows) {
                trivialCasesRemain = true;
                correctedSums[1] = ArrayUtils.removeElement(correctedSums[1], i);
                for (int j = 0; j < correctedSums[1].length; j++) {
                    correctedSums[1][j]--;
                }
            }

            valueEqualsDimension = false;

            for (int h = 0; h < correctedSums[1].length; i++) {
                if (correctedSums[1][h] == numRows) {
                    valueEqualsDimension = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!zeroesExist || !valueEqualsDimension) {
            trivialCasesRemain = false;
        }
    }

    return correctedSums;
}
```

Comment: Please improve your question, 1) starting with its non-informative title, 2) then telling us the results of your attempts to debug the problem, including running your code with a debugger.

Comment: Regarding your "fixed" title, `"Can someone help me correct the code?"`, Again, the title should be *informative*, something perhaps like: Why does program enter an endless loop? Your title tells ***nothing*** about your problem itself, only that you need help fixing a program -- but we all know that, else you wouldn't be here. Your title should summarize the problem you're having in an informative way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding,

> but the code gets stuck in a loop and I don't think it's doing what it's supposed to do.

Here:

```
for (int h = 0; h < correctedSums[1].length; i++) {
```

This loop will never end since `h` never changes within the loop. It should be:

```
for (int h = 0; h < correctedSums[1].length; h++) {
```

If you ran the code in a debugger, or used println's, you'd know what loop the code is stuck in, and this would allow you to inspect it immediately and correct it.

Comment: I ran the code, but after that, it only removed the first zero from the arrays. It didn't do the rest of what I specified. @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Comment: @Chromatica: then you've got a new separate problem, and still need to do debugging.